# Is there a way to deploy / update only static content to GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

There are many cases in which we run into a need to update only static content of a production GAE app.

Examples:

1. CSS changes, and other related resources, such as images
2. New HTML pages, API of the app stays the same (RESTful web services)
3. Client side flow changes (only JS)

Each of the above changes requires a full deployment.

I read the documentation (Java) and searched this forum (and others), and I'm pretty sure there's no such method exists.

Partial updates of the app in GAE is possible, like updating indexes, update cron jobs, backend management (deploy, start, stop, etc.), but nothing about update static content.

1. Does anyone know a way for just deploying / updating the static part of a GAE app?
2. Is this something that folks using GAE would need / use?

Answer (score 0):

Cant be done. File a feature requets!